# Can't insert value in db

Tags: php, database

I have a strange thing over here. I'm trying to insert a value in my database but it's not working for some reason. I have this code:

**PHP**:

```
<input type='file' name='images[]' />
<input type="text" name="newproject_name" id="tags"/>
<input type='text' name='order[]' value='$b' />

$project            = new Project();
$project->photo     = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
$project->order     = $_POST['order'][$key];            
$projectnaam        = $_POST['newproject_name'];

if($project->createProject($_DB)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NOT OK";
}
                                }
```

**FUNCTION**:

```
class Project {
    public function createProject($db) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblProject (
            project,
            photo,
            order)    // If you remove this line, the function is working
        VALUES(
            '".$db->escape($this->project)."',
            '".$db->escape($this->photo)."',
            '".$db->escape($this->order)."'    // If you remove this line, the function is working
            )";
        return $db->insert($sql);
    }
}
```

Strange thing is, when I delete the `order`-lines, the function is working just fine. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What is the result of running the query `EXPLAIN tblProject`?

Comment: Have you tried echo-ing the `$sql` variable and executing it directly in your DBMS?

Comment: Thank you all for the input, but the answer of jprofitt solved my problem!

Comment: You should really test the result of all queries and read the error message.

Comment: @AlvaroG.Vicario, any hint on how to do this properly?

Comment: @Michiel - You seem to be using a custom DB class. Such class should use the error reporting features provided by the underlying libraries and at least throw exceptions on SQL errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved word. If you use backticks around the column name you should be good:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblProject (
        `project`,
        `photo`,
        `order`)    
    VALUES(
        '".$db->escape($this->project)."',
        '".$db->escape($this->photo)."',
        '".$db->escape($this->order)."'  
        )";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the order column name to position or display_order.